# Establishing relationship between 2 diseases

Tags: correlation

I have the following data of 2 diseases from 5 areas. I want to see if there is any relationship between the 2 diseases.
Incidence Rates of 2 diseases (cases per million per year)

```
    Areas   Disease 1       Disease 2
    1       4.653           0.751
    2       6.910           1.121
    3       4.957           0.745
    4       2.870           0.848
    5       2.819           1.166

Actual number of cases are
Areas   Disease 1       Disease 2
1       1152            186
2       2601            422
3       1051            158
4        403            119
5        290            120
```

I am a beginner in Biostatistics. Kindly advise me in simple terms

Comment: What are those numbers? Are these average values, what is your sample size, etc. A little bit of context would be of great help.

Comment: @chl: The first paragraph shows the Incidence Rates of 2 diseases (cases per million per year) being compared
The second paragraph gives the actual number of cases of 2 diseases being compared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple answer for how to "establish a relationship between two variables;" indeed, your question is one of the central issues in statistics and research is still going on on how to do this.  But some basics:  first you will want to plot your data, and then you will want to carry out a linear regression to test some specific type of relationship between variables in your data.  You will need to obtain the "p-score" of the regression to get an idea of how well your purported relationship is supported by the data.  Generally if you can get a very low p-score (e.g. p < 0.01), then it will be safe to say that there is a relationship between variables.

Comment: A lower *p-value* does not mean that the observed effect is stronger.

Comment: Indeed, it is important for a statistician to understand the difference between statistical and practical significance.  I interpreted the OP's question as asking about statistical significance.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply and the clarification. I provided initially Incidence Rates. Now I added number of cases also for clarity

Comment: @chl♦: Thank you for the prompt clarification. I provided initially Incidence Rates. Now I added number of cases also for clarity.

Comment: The point made by chl is important: *any* p-value below your alpha level of *statistical* significance is in the safe area to reject the null hypothesis, and further distance of the alpha level will *not* indicate further *substantive* significance. This applies to the formal model behind your scatterplot and its fitted regression line, just like it will apply if you detect a non-linear relationship, either visually or through formal diagnostics, and then switch to more advanced techniques in order to model it.